# How do i set the pixel size of patches?

Tags: netlogo

I need to be able to draw out roads in the u.i. It is therefore important that I am able to adjust the size of the patches that I use to do this. Please could somebody give an example of source code that I may use to achieve this? cheers

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once. It wastes people's time.

Comment: Seth I do not mean to anger you, I only wish to quench my thirst for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

No source code as such but you can make the roads more than one patch wide or give the patches a width variable maybe using pcolor for
 visualization.

```
Ask patches with[road?][set pcolor brown + width]
```